# Moving lines internally in emacs 24.4

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have this snippet of code in my .emacs file that should move lines of code up or down. This works fine on 24.3.1 but not fully on 24.4.

moving lines down work, as the line would be swapped with the bottom line and the "cursor" would move as well.

Moving the line up however, it will swap but the cursor stay on the same line without moving up along with the line.

Is there a reason for that?

```
;; Moving a line up or down
(defun move-text-internal (arg)
  (cond
   ((and mark-active transient-mark-mode)
    (if (> (point) (mark))
        (exchange-point-and-mark))
    (let ((column (current-column))
          (text (delete-and-extract-region (point) (mark))))
      (forward-line arg)
      (move-to-column column t)
      (set-mark (point))
      (insert text)
      (exchange-point-and-mark)
      (setq deactivate-mark nil)))
   (t
    (let ((column (current-column)))
      (beginning-of-line)
      (when (or (> arg 0) (not (bobp)))
        (forward-line)
        (when (or (< arg 0) (not (eobp)))
          (transpose-lines arg))
        (forward-line -1))
      (move-to-column column t)))))

(defun move-text-down (arg)
  "Move region (transient-mark-mode active) or current line
  arg lines down."
  (interactive "*p")
  (move-text-internal arg))
;(global-set-key [M-S-down] 'move-text-down)
(global-set-key [A-M-down] 'move-text-down)

(defun move-text-up (arg)
  "Move region (transient-mark-mode active) or current line
  arg lines up."
  (interactive "*p")
  (move-text-internal (- arg)))
;(global-set-key [M-S-up]   'move-text-up)
(global-set-key [A-M-up]   'move-text-up)
```

Comment: There are a number of examples and libraries that already do this -- have you look at any of them, instead of trying to fix your own implementation?  For example:  https://github.com/targzeta/move-lines and http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Transpose.html and http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/02/move-current-line-up-or-down/ and http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MoveLine

Comment: Thank you lawlist, this worked for me   http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/02/move-current-line-up-or-down/